# After run the cron sitemap links are not work properly

Tags: xml-sitemap

After ran the cron i am not getting any error but it did not display the xmlsitemap links properly.please help me what will i do now?

I checked in dblogs, there I got this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM uc_orders uc_orders WHERE .uid = 1 LIMIT 0, 5' at
>   line 2 query: SELECT FROM uc_orders uc_orders WHERE .uid = 1 LIMIT 0,
>   5 in
>   sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc
>   on line 807.

Not display the link proprely means:
suppose mysite is www.example.com. In url i typed www.example.com/sitemap.xml under this link i got inncorrect links.

Comment: that error has nothing to do with sitemaps, presumably it's an old error. we still need to know what you mean by 'it did not display xmlsitemap links properly'.. where did it not display them? how are they set up to look? how do they look now? are you displaying it on screen? or just the `sitemap.xml` file? etc. We need more information in order to properly help you